# Gradle : Multiple subtasks share the same extension variable object

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin, gradle-custom-plugin

I have created a custom Gradle plugin like this,

**DummyPlugin.java**

```
public class DummyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("dummy", DummyTask.class);
        project.getExtensions().create("dummy", DummyExtension.class);
    }
}
```

**DummyTask.java**

```
public class DummyTask extends Test {
    @TaskAction
    public void dummy() {
        Project project = getProject();
        DummyExtension extension = project.getExtensions().findByType(DummyExtension.class);
        System.out.println("Env of dummy is " + extension.getEnv());
    }
}
```

**DummyExtension.java**

```
public class DummyExtension {
    private String env;

    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
    }
}
```

Now, I have created three tasks for different environments, like this :

```
apply plugin: 'dummy'

task dummyCI(type: DummyTask) {
    dummy {
        env = 'ci'
    }
}

task dummyDev(type: DummyTask) {
    dummy {
        env = 'dev'
    }
}

task dummyTest(type: DummyTask) {
    dummy {
        env = 'test'
    }
}
```

But, on running `./gradlew dummyCI`, instead of getting `Env of dummy is ci`, I'm getting `Env of dummy is test`. Same for `./gradlew dummyDev` also.

How do I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the extension property in the configuration phase which always runs. So each invocation is overriding the previous. To set it in the execution phase, use a `doFirst { ... }` block. Eg:

```
task dummyCI(type: DummyTask) {
    doFirst {
        dummy {
            env = 'ci'
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps a better solution is to get rid of the extension object all together and instead add the `env` property (input?) to the `DummyTask`